# Moving from pure OpenID to OpendID with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)

Tags: authentication, openid, dotnetopenauth, wif

### Background

We currently use OpenID for authentication of users, and use the Claimed Identity we get back to link the authentication with a 'contact' record in our database.

### Problem

We're now looking to add WIF to the mix, however I'm worried that by adding this extra layer will will no longer receive the same Claimed Identity values back from WIF (i.e. those of OpenID).

### Question

What do we do about all our existing users, which currently have OpenID claimed identity strings as their 'id'? How can we link those users to their OpenIDs once WIF is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this, so just in-case anyone else is stumped:

If you read this [blog post on WIF](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2009/07/14/openid-ws-fed-protocol-transition-sts/), you'll see that the original Claimed Identity from the provider is returned and applied within the [ClaimsIdentity Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748212.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely follow what you are doing, but if you are adding other identity providers (and keeping OpenID) you might want to considier using ACS (Access Control Service). Your app will just use 1 library (WIF) and you would outsource dealing with different protocols and identity providers to ACS.

The end result is a very clean (and future proof) solution.

ACS supports out of the box: any OpenID IdP, any WS-Federation IdP, Yahoo!, Google and Facebook.